# PSD to HTML/CSS Conversion

Tags: html, css, photoshop

I'm currently getting a site designed by a person who works in photoshop and will supply me with a PSD of the site - quite a few layers etc...

Is there any method to convert this to HTML/CSS or does this have to be done manually?

Some sites seem to offer the service but I'm not sure if they just cut the PSD into sections and display them as images rather then HTML/CSS.

Maybe full conversion just isn't possible.

thoughts? thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way is to do this manually, or pay someone to write it in HTML for you. Websites that just cut the PSD up often produce bad and sometimes plain invalid HTML.

You are likely to get better results (a faster loading page, better SEO, better semantics, etc) by using a layout that isn't primarily sliced images.

Answer (score 0):

Many sites will do exactly what you specify they do.

Search for reviews of PSD to HTML / CSS service providers and compare rates / turnaround times / quality.

You can also use newer tools like http://csshat.com that will help to a large extent.

Answer (score 0):

Photoshop can convert a layout to a god-awful fix layout with numbered ids and classes. You don't want that as it is a nightmare. The best and only way really is to slice the layout, name the slices appropriately and then export them. Then code your html / css by hand. This is what everyone does so there's nothing wrong with that. Of course your html / css needs to be good to do a good job but that's why we get paid.

BTW. Using lots of images in layouts and images with text in is very bad practice. There are few excuses for this now except maybe custom marketing material. If there's a font you need then you can use Cufon for this. Rounded corners can be achieved with css in many cases. Some of my recent layouts have used as little as 5-10kb of images in total.

Obviously you can't be expected to do that as a newbie but that's what you should aim for.

Answer (score 0):

You should have it done manually.

There are automatic tools ([1](http://www.adobe.com/products/muse.html), [2](http://www.medialab.com/)) that can do the conversion, but the output code is simply awful. Don't expect to be able to maintain the code easily, afterwards.

There is also sites that can code it for you. They should follow the usual tips & tricks on how do it well. Some are ok, some are not.

Or you can learn to do it. Simply code it by hand. It's not difficult, but you need some basic knowledge of HTML, CSS before.

Look at each block of design/layout/box/etc., then see what elements it has and how can you do re-create them using HTML/CSS. If there isn't an answer to one.

You can find tutorials about it ([3](http://www.google.com/search?q=convert+psd+tutorial)), guides ([4](http://artmov.com/ebooks/how-to-convert-psd-to-html-css)) and videos ([5](http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=convert%20psd&oq=convert%20psd)) as well. It's a pretty flooded with info on this.

([1](http://www.adobe.com/products/muse.html)) Adobe Muse: http://www.adobe.com/products/muse.html

([2](http://www.medialab.com/)) SideGrinder 3: http://www.medialab.com/

([3](http://www.google.com/search?q=convert+psd+tutorial)) Google: http://www.google.com/search?q=convert+psd+tutorial

([4](http://artmov.com/ebooks/how-to-convert-psd-to-html-css)) Artmov: http://artmov.com/ebooks/how-to-convert-psd-to-html-css

([5](http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=convert%20psd&oq=convert%20psd)) YouTube: [http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=convert+psd&oq=convert+psd](http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=convert%20psd&oq=convert%20psd)